# Using console commands in python

Tags: python, linux, console, command, nic

I am using console commands in python, however, it is not outputting the value I want.

The path is:

```
#ifconfig -a | grep "HWaddr"
```

From this command I get:

```
eth0     Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 30:9E:D5:C7:1z:EF
eth1     Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 30:0E:95:97:0A:F0
```

I need to use console commands to retrieve that value, so this is what I have so far for code:

```
def getmac():
    mac=subprocess.check_output('ifconfig -a | grep "HWaddr"')
print "%s" %(mac)
```

I basically only want to retrieve the hardware address which is 30:0E:D5:C7:1A:F0. My code above doesn't retrieve that. My question is how do I use console commands to get the value I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess

def getmac(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

command = "ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr" 
print "%s" %(getmac(command).split()[9])
# or print out the entire list to see which index your HWAddr corresponds to
# print "%s" %(getmac(command).split())
```

Or as per user heemayl,

```
command = "cat /sys/class/net/eth1/address"
print "%s" %(getmac(command))
```

**Note:** 
1. Using `shell=True` isn't recommended as per [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)
2. This isn't as efficient compared to the normal ways of reading a file in Python.

You could have also returned

```
subprocess.check_output(command)
```

However, in the above case, you might get an `OSError` or a `CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)` depending on whether you passed your commands as a list, which can be solved if you explicitly mention your python path as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888222/subprocess-module-fails-to-run-command)

Comment: Reading a (pseudo) file with `cat` in a `subprocess` is _very_ inefficient compared to the normal ways of reading a file in Python file.

Comment: Sure it isn't as efficient! The OP wanted to use console commands in python, hence the answer. I have edited my answer to include that fact.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust and easy way in Linux to get the MAC address is to get it from `sysfs`, mounted on `/sys`.

For interface `etho`, the location would be `/sys/class/net/eth0/address`; Similarly for `eth1`, it would be `/sys/class/net/eth1/address`.

```
% cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address 
74:d4:35:XX:XX:XX
```

So, you could just read the file in `python` too:

```py
with open('/sys/class/net/eth0/address') as f:
    mac_eth0 = f.read().rstrip()
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not print out the value still

Comment: @Nikkibee Are you sure you have used the right interface name? At first check with running the command directly in terminal..

Comment: @Nikkibee: heemayl's code only fetches the info, it doesn't print it.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159195/4104748).

Python 2.5 includes an uuid implementation which (in at least one version) needs the mac address. You can import the mac finding function into your own code easily:

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
mac = get_mac()
```

The return value is the mac address as 48 bit integer.